# Array index of functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an array that acts like the contents page of a book. Here is what I'm trying:

```
var section = [someFunction(pInput.value), anotherFunction(pInput.value), function3(pInput.value)];
var sectionNum = 0;

var playerInput = function () {
    var pInput = document.getElementById('input');
    section[sectionNum];
};
```

EDIT:
My functions wont execute, so when I run the code nothing happens.

To sum up, I want to know if I'm coding it wrong or if there is another way to do it.

Thanks for the help,
~Gateway

Comment: The question is not clear.

Comment: I think your functions will execute when you define your array, not when you try to call them inside your `playerInput` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should restructure your code along these lines:

```
var section = [someFunction, anotherFunction, function3];

var sectionNum = 0;

var playerInput = function () {
    var pInput = document.getElementById('input');
    section[sectionNum](pInput.value);
};
```

But please be sure to put in some nice checks that `sectionNum` has a legal value at all times.

Answer (score 1):

The `section` array is storing the values returned by each function rather than the functions themselves.

You probably meant to do something like this:

```
var section = [someFunction, anotherFunction, function3];
var sectionNum = 0;

var playerInput = function () {
    var pInput = document.getElementById('input');
    section[sectionNum](pInput.value);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting your functions inside of an array and trying to call them from there based on the sectionNum. You could use a switch statement; which in my opinion makes it easier to read:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

In your case it would be something like:

```
switch (sectionNum) {
  case 0:
    someFunction(pInput.value)
    break;
  case 1:
    anotherFunction(pInput.value)
    break;
  case 2:
    function3(pInput.value)
    break;
  default:
    alert("I don't know that number")
    break;
}
```

The only downside is that you can't add more functions on the go as you can with the array.